# Java приложение - запустить каждое http-подключение в своей среде выполнения

Tags: java, spring-boot

Создал приложение на Java на spring boot. Объявил переменную `int x=0;`

Открыл его через браузер, и в переменную x записал `x=1;`

Открыл во второй вкладке браузера это же приложение, и уже в ней через веб-интерфейс, например через html-элемент , присвоил `x=2`.

Если третий клиент в третьей вкладке запишет в `x=3`, то у предыдущих двух клиентов `x` тоже будет равен трем, и например при нажатии на какую-нибудь кнопку для просмотра результата запустится код

```
if (x = 0) System.out.println("x = 0")
elseif (x = 1) System.out.println("x = 1")
else if (x = 2) System.out.println("x = 2")
else if (x = 3) System.out.println("x = 3")
```

и у всех троих выведется одно и то же, а именно: x=3;

Т.е. одно приложение в состоянии выполняться только в одном потоке.
Как решить эту проблему?

Comment: Ничего подобного, каждый http-запрос обрабатывается в отдельном потоке. А описанные вами симптомы связаны с тем, что все бины - это синглтоны, включая контроллеры.

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev Я не совсем понимаю как выполняется приложение. Оно запущено на сервере через java -jar, и находится в оперативной памяти машины-сервера вместе со всеми своими переменными. Когда я обращаюсь к приложению через http, то изменяю переменную x на x=2, например. http-запрос завершился, но мое приложение по-прежнему осталось в оперативной памяти с x=2. Вопрос в том, как работает приложение запущенное на java, и как сделать так чтобы каждый юзер обращался к нему как с чистого листа?

Comment: Это просто, достаточно хранить данные только в локальных переменных метода.

Comment: я наверное понял. Когда заходим с браузера, то создаем объект контроллера. Он выполняет запрос, затем http-запрос завершается, и объект удаляется сборщиком мусора. При повторном обращении даже на ту же самую страницу того же самого юзера создастся новый объект контроллера, и так при каждом http-обращении будет создаваться объект, который отработает а затем уничтожится сборщиком мусора. Я верно описал?

Comment: Объект контроллера создаётся один раз - при запуске сервера. Каждый новый запрос в отдельном потоке запускает методы контроллера. Если переменная `x` объявлена внутри метода, то память под неё выделяется в стековом кадре и переменная существует ровно столько времени, сколько выполняется метод. Если переменная объявлена как поле класса, то память под неё выделяется в куче и она не удалится до тех пора, пока сервер не будет остановлен.